# Due to the movement of charge inside a cavity in a spherical or random shell, the charge on the outer surface of the body does not change. Why?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

I have read the same in many textbooks. What's happening inside the cavity does not have anything to do with the surface charge. But I am not understanding the reason for this.

Comment: You may want to first read example 2.10 in Introduction to Electrodynamics (4th ed.) by Griffiths and then read this related [Phy.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530263/how-is-the-uniqueness-theorem-is-used-in-this-example) post. Together, they should help address your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the statement in the question title nor that in the question body is in fact generally correct.

The important assumptions here are:

- We are talking about *electrostatics*, that is static electric fields generated by static charges.
- The object with a cavity is a *conductor*.

Then the statement essentially follows from the following facts:

1. In electrostatic equilibrium, any net charge carried by a conductor is localized on its surface (inner or outer).
2. The electric field inside the conducting material itself vanishes, hence the electric potential is constant throughout the conductor.
3. The boundary value problem for the Laplace equation (which describes the electric potential in absence of electric charge) has a unique solution.

Let us see what this implies in the concrete situation that some electric charge is placed in a cavity in a conductor. Then the above points 1 and 2 together imply that the total charge induced on the inner surface of the conductor (the boundary of the cavity) must just cancel the charge placed in the cavity; anything else would violate the Gauss law. As a consequence, a total charge equal to the total charge placed in the cavity will be induced on the outer surface of the conductor. (Here I assume for concreteness that the conductor is electrically neutral as a whole.) Finally, by the above point 3, the electric field outside the conductor is fully determined by the total charge on its surface (or the potential of the surface with respect to infinity) and the geometry of the surface. The field does not depend at all on the size and shape of the cavity and on the distribution of charge in the cavity.

Similar reasoning explains why the charge inside the cavity is not affected by any charged placed on the outer surface of the conductor, or by any electric fields external to the conductor. All this is pretty standard textbook material, and it is certainly not just stated without explanation. Here I just wanted to emphasize that we are talking about electrostatics. If you actually want to *move* the charge in the cavity, you will generate time-dependent electric and magnetic fields, which can certainly affect both the bulk of the conductor and its outside.

Answer (score 0):

consider a  point charge +q(**assume element x**) brought to center of spherical shell with **uniformly distributed positive charge** **+ q over its outer surface** for simplicity, since x is inside the conductor the electric field due to x and shell will cancel out each other at every point through out the conductor(shell), so every point must have a constant voltage(dV =Edx, E=0 so V=constant), so if you move element x anywhere inside shell, work done is zero(**element x doesn't apply potential due it over itself**). hence to move charge any where due to constant voltage potential due to shell on x must remain same , no matter where we want to transfer x within the shell from center or anywhere, and we know potential due to uniformly charged shell inside is constant(depends only on outer surface charge and radius), because radius of shell cannot change so charge on outer shouldn't change as well ,to keep potential at every point same. *its also amazing that if I bring x from infinity to any point on shell, not necessary its center the potential change would be same.*